# Trigger bitbucket pipeline in absence of a tag

Tags: tags, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to trigger a different bitbucket pipeline depending on whether my commit has a git tag or not. I can trigger a pipeline for tag-containing commits with this code in my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`:

```
pipelines:
  tags:
    '*':
      - <code for tagged pipeline>
```

but I am unable to trigger the other pipeline in **absence** of a tag.

I am aware of the possibility to run a `default` pipeline when no tag is present, but this will also trigger unnecessarily when a tag is present.

Is there a way to only trigger the other pipeline when no tag is present?

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/71959156/11715259